# Converting genotype data in R

Tags: r

I have this matrix called `mymat`(approx dim of 446664 X 234). It has REF and ALT columns where they could have any of A,T,G,C letters (only one letter). In the columns ending with .GT, I want to replace these letters. The condition to match is, if there is 0, I want to replace it with the letter in `REF` column and if there is 1 then I want to replace it with the letter in `ALT` column. If there is NA, I want to replace it with "0" "0" (i.e., zero space zero). Finally I need to invert all the `.GT` columns across the rows (transpose) as shown in the `result`. In the result, everything is separated by space.

```
mymat<-structure(list(REF = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"C", "G", "T"), class = "factor"), ALT = structure(c(6L, 6L, 
1L, 9L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "A", "A", "A,T", "C", "C", "C", 
"G", "G", "T"), class = "factor"), X860.GT = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NA", "0/0", "0/1", "0/1", "1/1"), class = "factor"), 
    X861.GT = structure(c(1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NA", 
    "0/0", "0/1", "0/1", "1/1", "1/1"), class = "factor"), X862.GT = structure(c(6L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("NA", "0/0", "0/1", "0/1", "1/1", 
    "1/1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("REF", "ALT", "X860.GT", 
"X861.GT", "X862.GT"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

result

```
X860 0 0 T C G G 0 0 0 0
X861 0 0 C C G G 0 0 0 0 
X862 C C T C 0 0 C C 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite elegant but gets the job done.

```
m = as.data.frame(lapply(mymat, as.character), stringsAsFactors=F)
m[m=="NA"] = '0 0'

fix = function(x) {
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (x[i] == '0/0') {
      x[i] = paste(m[i,1], m[i,1])
    }
    else if (x[i] == '0/1') {
      x[i] = paste(m[i,1], m[i,2])
    }
    else if (x[i] == '1/0') {
      x[i] = paste(m[i,2], m[i,1])
    }
    else if (x[i] == '1/1') {
      x[i] = paste(m[i,2], m[i,2])
    }
  }
  x
}

m[,3:5] <- lapply(m[,3:5], fix)
m = t(data.frame(lapply(m[,3:5], function (x) unlist (strsplit(x," ")))))
rownames(m) = sub(".GT","",rownames(m))
```

Output of `m`:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
X860 "0"  "0"  "T"  "C"  "G"  "G"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  
X861 "0"  "0"  "C"  "C"  "G"  "G"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  
X862 "C"  "C"  "T"  "C"  "0"  "0"  "C"  "C"  "0"  "0"
```